# failed defining the timestamp from csv file

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to store data into my Athena DB from S3 and I have date time format that looks like this :-

> **20171011133902**

I am trying to set format to timestamp but it is not recognizable, thus no data was inserted into the table.
I set the the format as bigint just to insert the data and my query looks something like this.

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.elb_logs (
>   'request_timestamp' bigint,  'id' int, .....)

I tried to convert in Quicksight, however when I edit data fields and change it to date, i became like this :-

> **2033-12-02T01:51:53.000Z**

Can someone help me on how I can handle this type of date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend loading your date time as a string, then parsing it to a timestamp in your select queries using the [parse_datetime](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime) function.  For JSON data like:

```
{"dt": "20171011133902", ... }
```

And your date/time field defined as a string:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scratch.test_dates (
  `dt` string
)
...
```

A query using `parse_datetime` to reformat dt as a proper timestamp:

```
SELECT
  parse_datetime(dt, 'YYYYMMddHHmmss') as parsed_date
FROM 
  scratch."test_dates"
```

Will yield a timestamp with timezone (as UTC in your case):

```
2017-10-11 13:39:02.000 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions :-

1. I did used parseDate function on Quicksight and it worked. (without changing the datatype on Athena DB) -->only works when you are not using SPICE

> parseDate(uploadtimestamp, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')

2. I also figured out that I need to change it String (on Athena DB) in order for the conversion to date button to work correctly on QuickSight.

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.elb_logs ( 'request_timestamp' string, 'id' int, .....)